# PHP system() call doesn't work when called by shell

Tags: php, linux, shell

I have a shell file that I run by cron:

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /var/www/test.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

That file contains just this line:

```
php -q /var/www/test.php
```

That php file contains this:

```
<?php
$command = 'cairosvg -f pdf -o /var/www/test.pdf /var/www/test.svg';
system($command);
$command = 'mkdir /var/www/test_dir';
system($command);
file_put_contents('var/www/test_user.log', posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name']);
if (file_exists('/var/www/test.pdf')) {
    file_put_contents('/var/www/test.log', 'success');
} else {
    file_put_contents('/var/www/test.log', 'fail');
}
```

`cairosvg` is a CLI library that turns SVG files into PDFs. This PHP code runs if I go through the steps above, but the file isn't created. If I call the PHP file through URL, the file is created.

The only difference I see is that the process user `posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name']` is `www-data` when ran by URL and `root` when ran by shell.

The command `cairosvg -f pdf -o /var/www/test.pdf /var/www/test.svg` works when I run it myself in terminal as root.

The second command, `mkdir /var/www/test_dir` is just a reality check to ensure that `system()` is enable for CLI or something else extremely simple. That command works by both shell and URL.

This is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of a problem on more complex system, so "skip the shell step" or similar answers aren't going to be very helpful for me.

I am running PHP 5.6, Ubuntu 14.04, and Apache.

**Why is this PHP code failing when I call by shell rather than when I call it by URL?**

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: Have a look at the return value of `system`, it should contain the output of the command. Is the destination file writable for your user?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for the advice. I dumped the output of `exec` but it gave nothing, but `system` return status gives `127`. Googling that now. The user is root so yes it should have write access.

Comment: @Goose exit code 127, apparently showing that your cli doesn't know any cairosvg command. I suggest to use full path for binary

Comment: @pomaxa that works! If you post that as an answer, I'll gladly accept!

Comment: Please have a look at this excelent answer and look at the section *cron runs your command in a restricted environment*
https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to Nico Haase, pomaxa and kvantour in the comments.

`system()` return status gives 127. That indicates the user (root) didn't recognize the cairosvg command. I symlinked `/usr/bin/cairosvg` to `/usr/local/bin/cairosvg` and that got everything working.

The reason root inside of shell didn't have access to cairosvg local is [explained here](https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it) under *CRON runs your command in a restricted environment*.

> What environment variables are available is likely to be very limited. Typically, you'll only get a few variables defined, such as $LOGNAME, $HOME, and $PATH.